# Okay to shift toilet a couple of inches?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

My toilet is set in a corner and is not square to the walls, so that when sitting on it, one’s left knee almost touches the wall-mounted TP dispenser. I can’t relocate the entire toilet, but shifting it slightly so the tank is parallel to the back wall and perpendicular to the side wall would help...even if just a little. It is NOT bolted to the floor. Truly, about an inch and a half is all that’s needed. I’m a senior lady and can physically manage this, just don’t want to create an issue that’d require a plumber. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you move the toilet paper dispenser? Or is it inset into the wall?

Comment: Can’t move the dispenser. It is ceramic and the wall is ceramic tile. House is 70 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your toilet is a fully self contained unit, such as chamber pot, it will be connected to plumbing. There will be the water line that brings water to fill the flush tank and then there will be the large diameter drain pipe that comes up through the floor and seals with the bottom of the toilet stool.

An arbitrary movement of the toilet unit will involve these plumbing connections so either you or a plumber will have to deal with the changes.

There is one specific thing that may be possible that would minimize the overall amount of plumbing impact. If you were to plan to simply rotate the toilet stool directly in line with the centerline of the drain pipe connection in the floor then all that would be needed there is a cleaning of the bottom of the stool and flange. You would then seat the toilet on a new wax ring or other new fangled rubber seal.

Rotating as described above will change the position where the water fill line engages the bottom of the flush tank. It that is currently plumbed with a rigid fixed position pipe then it will need to be redone. Replacing with a flexible stainless steel braid jacketed connection hose would make reconnection easy.

Comment: It should really be bolted to the floor too.

Comment: Just bought this older house and am trying to improve the bathroom. I was surprised to discover the bolts were “just for show.” Based on your answer, I’d best leave it alone until I can afford to pay a plumber. Thank you.

Comment: @Dallassal, even attempting to move the toilet just to see if it is really bolted can damage the wax seal and cause it to leak.  If you moved the toilet at all - even lifted a corner to get a peek, I would worry abut a leak.  That's why they _should_ be bolted down.  The seal is literally just a chunk of wax with no stabilization (assuming a standard floor-draining toilet).

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. I’m having it looked at.